# Rxweb validators not working with mat inputs

Tags: angular-material

**Rxweb validator in angular**

when I compare two inputs with conditions, if x has value then y should have required validation. when I give value for x and not value for y. The form is also valid.

when I give value to X and value to y and then deleting for Y it shows required.

I need when I give value for x automatically required should show for y field.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @karthikeyan D please show your component code or share stackblitz example